# When to adjust for multiple hypthesis?

Tags: statistical-inference

I am potentially doing multiple pairwise comparisons in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4376856/21163) question and the [cited](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4376856/21163) answer warns me to adjust for multiple comparisons using for example Bonferroni. However, I am not sure what p-values to adjust by how much.

Szenario:
I have a sack of fruites with Apples, Oranges, and Pears which can either be ripe or not.

When I am testing if any of the fruits differs significantly in the amount of ripeness from the other fruits, I am performing 3 tests and thus need to use $\alpha/3$ as the adjusted significance level. However, what if I now test a second attribute, i.e., sweetness? Is this a different test battery and I again need to adjust only to $\alpha/3$ or do I now perform 6 tests and thus have to adjust to $\alpha/6$?

Finally, I have a second sack of fruits with dates, tomatoes, and strawberries for which I also want to perform the same test battery. Does this mean I have the same adjustments again (either $\alpha/3$ or $\alpha/6$) or do those tests also count towards the test count and I have to up the overall adjustment to $\alpha/6$ or $\alpha/12$?

**When adjusting $\alpha$ for multiple significance tests what tests count towards the adjustment denominator when using Bonferroni?**

Answer (score 1):

The Bonferroni method controls the *familywise error rate (FWER)*, which is the probability of rejecting at least one true null hypothesis. Particularly, it uses a significance level of $\alpha/N$ for each test to ensure the FWER for $N$ tests is  no more than $\alpha$. It doesn't matter how these tests relate to one another; if you care about the FWER among $N$ total tests, then you use $\alpha/N$.

However, it is also worth noting that the Bonferroni method is a very conservative approach in that it over-rejects null hypotheses and doesn't lead to enough "discovery." A more powerful procedure that still controls the FWER at level $\alpha$ is the [Holm method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method).

You may also be interested in controlling something other than FWER, such as the [false discovery rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate). There are many other approaches to deal with the [multiple testing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).